# Linq Sort by Date

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a list of date strings in the following format

```
Apr-2016
Aug-2015
Nov-2015
Oct-2015
Sep-2015
July 2016
```

Code:

```
var sortedMonths = monthList
            .Select(x => new { month = x, Sort = DateTime.ParseExact(x, "MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) })
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Sort.Month)
            .Select(x => x.month)
            .ToList();
```

I have used to above statement but the list is still not ordered.

Comment: Your need to order by year and month, don't you?

Comment: Are you sure that it should be sorted only by month (x.Sort.Month) and not by whole DateTime field (x.Sort)?

Comment: `Array.Sort()`, `IComparer<MeModel>` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to order by the entire DateTime object, not just the Month:

```
var sortedMonths = monthList
            .Select(x => new { month = x, Sort = DateTime.ParseExact(x, "MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) })
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Sort)
            .Select(x => x.month)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Why saving `month` and `sort`? Just parse to datetime and sort by it directly? They will all be the first of a month anyway.

Answer (score 1):

please make sure the date strings are in correct format.

```
July-2016
```

should be

```
Jul-2016
```

Here is the working sample that sorts by the date descending

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Globalization;

public class TestSortDateStrings
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var monthList = new List<string> {"Apr-2016", "Aug-2015", "Nov-2015", "Oct-2015", "Sep-2015", "Jul-2016"};
        var sortedMonths = monthList
            .Select(x => new { month = x, Sort = DateTime.ParseExact(x, "MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) })
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Sort)
            .Select(x => x.month)
            .ToList();

        foreach(var m in sortedMonths)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m);
        }
    }
}
```

and you will get same result if you first sort by year and then by month

```
.OrderByDescending(x => x.Sort.Year)
.ThenByDescending(x => x.Sort.Month)
```

Output is

```
Jul-2016
Apr-2016
Nov-2015
Oct-2015
Sep-2015
Aug-2015
```